# Exception in thread main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I am getting an error message from the output when I typed : 199.99

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2388)
    at myproject2.Myproject2.main(Myproject2.java:11)
```

but my code doesn't have any errors:

```
package myproject2;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Myproject2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter purchase amount: ");
    double purchaseAmount = input.nextDouble();

    double tax = purchaseAmount * 0.06;
    System.out.println("Sales tax is " + (int)(tax * 100) / 100.0);


    }

}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Hmm. The stack trace shows `nextFloat`, but your code shows `nextDouble`. Are you sure that stack trace was obtained by running that code?

Comment: Did you give input other than a number?

Comment: And what locale are you running in? I wonder whether it was expecting "199,99".

Comment: @Vamshi : No I'm sure I give a number and I'm getting this error for any number but integer.

Comment: Did u try using Locale.US/Locale.UK based on your location?

Comment: If you solved your problem, don't just add [Solved] to your title. Perhaps tell us how you solved it in an answer. Or if one of the answers solved it for you, accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `nextDouble` method expects the input to be like `A,B`. If your input is `199,99`, there will be no errors.

If you want it to accept doubles the way you said, you can set the `Locale` to your `Scanner`.

```
input.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: the expected input depends on the current locale

Answer (score 0):

```
input.useLocale(Locale.UK);
```

You need to provide the Scanner's locale.

E.g.

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.UK);
```

Comment: I'm newbie in java and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide you with an example.